# TensorFlow GPU doesn't recognize GPU dlls

Tags: python, tensorflow

I followed the following website to install the necessary GPU Support for Tensorflow 2.4.1: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu  followed by the actual Tensorflow installation: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip. I then run a sample snippet of code which should check the GPU and try running a tensor. It says it cannot see certain CUDA files, of which I pasted all of the files below (that also match with the path). I pasted all of the relevant information I could think of below.

I checked to make sure all of the dll's were created properly:

```
PS C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin> ls


    Directory: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         2/13/2021  10:04 PM                crt
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM         203776 bin2c.exe
-ar---         7/27/2020   4:11 PM             58 compute-sanitizer.bat
-a----          8/4/2020   1:57 AM       89057280 cublas64_11.dll
-a----          8/4/2020   1:57 AM      167523328 cublasLt64_11.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM         373248 cuda-memcheck.exe
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM        4604928 cudafe++.exe
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM         335872 cudart32_110.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM         401408 cudart64_110.dll
-a----         2/13/2021   8:49 PM         222720 cudnn64_8.dll
-a----         2/13/2021   8:49 PM       99908096 cudnn_adv_infer64_8.dll
-a----         2/13/2021   8:49 PM       65183232 cudnn_adv_train64_8.dll
-a----         2/13/2021   8:49 PM      508834304 cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll
-a----         2/13/2021   8:49 PM       51145728 cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll
-a----         2/13/2021   8:49 PM      240333312 cudnn_ops_infer64_8.dll
-a----         2/13/2021   8:49 PM       25651712 cudnn_ops_train64_8.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM      162878976 cufft64_10.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM         272896 cufftw64_10.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM        1305600 cuinj64_110.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM        2828800 cuobjdump.exe
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM       52446720 curand64_10.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM      525173248 cusolver64_10.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM      314601984 cusolverMg64_10.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM      159789568 cusparse64_11.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM         302080 fatbinary.exe
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM         232448 nppc64_11.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM       10907648 nppial64_11.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM        4569600 nppicc64_11.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM        7840256 nppidei64_11.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM       51866112 nppif64_11.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM       26065920 nppig64_11.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM        6411264 nppim64_11.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM       20231168 nppist64_11.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM         203264 nppisu64_11.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM        2856960 nppitc64_11.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:59 AM        8873472 npps64_11.dll
-a----          8/4/2020   1:57 AM         299520 nvblas64_11.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM         408576 nvcc.exe
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM            334 nvcc.profile
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM       28080128 nvdisasm.exe
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM        3133952 nvjpeg64_11.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM        7523328 nvlink.exe
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM        2173440 nvprof.exe
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM         225792 nvprune.exe
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM        5118976 nvrtc-builtins64_110.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM       16161792 nvrtc64_110_0.dll
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM             53 nvvp.bat
-a----         7/23/2020   6:58 AM        7407104 ptxas.exe
```

Here is my path:

> C:\Users\jnels>echo %PATH% C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
> Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
> Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\libnvvp;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA
> Corporation\Nsight Compute 2020.1.2;C:\Program
> Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Users\jnels\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

I then followed the instructions for running a sample code which will test the GPU & Tensorflow to see if it works. I should expect to see a tensor returned:

```
PS C:\Users\jnels> python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
2021-02-13 23:24:28.372069: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-02-13 23:24:28.372201: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2021-02-13 23:24:29.637123: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-13 23:24:29.638344: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-02-13 23:24:29.692627: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:0b:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3080 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.71GHz coreCount: 68 deviceMemorySize: 10.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 707.88GiB/s
2021-02-13 23:24:29.692892: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2021-02-13 23:24:29.694758: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
2021-02-13 23:24:29.695158: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
2021-02-13 23:24:29.695609: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
2021-02-13 23:24:29.696010: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
2021-02-13 23:24:29.696368: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found
2021-02-13 23:24:29.696722: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
2021-02-13 23:24:29.697079: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2021-02-13 23:24:29.697327: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-02-13 23:24:29.698128: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-02-13 23:24:29.699113: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-02-13 23:24:29.699192: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]
2021-02-13 23:24:29.699571: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
tf.Tensor(1250.3312, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Update your GPU driver. Install Cuda toolkit, and CuDNN properly. Make sure if any python version if matters. TensorFlow instruction is clean enough, it should work.

Comment: Uninstall previous or old installation before start new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added all required installation directories to your path environment variables to support `tensorflow_gpu`.

Add the `CUDA®`, `CUPTI`, and `cuDNN` installation directories to the `%PATH%` environmental variable as below and update your `%PATH%` to match:

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\bin;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\extras\CUPTI\lib64;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.0\include;%PATH%
SET PATH=C:\tools\cuda\bin;%PATH%
```

You can refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup) link for more detailed information in this.